# How do you style the label for a Silverlight ToggleSwitch?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

I am wanting to change the foreground colour of a Silverlight ToggleSwitch, although when i open the object in ExpressionBlend i have no object items to edit.

How is this done? (without rebuilding OR using reflector)?

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure what you are doing wrong in Blend, however, you can see the template for the ToggleSwitch if you look at the sourcecode for ToggleSwitch here:

http://silverlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61620#1325059

Ignoring the storyboards / VisualStateManager, the control has the following markup:

```
<Grid x:Name="SwitchRoot" Background="Transparent" Height="95" Width="136">
    <Grid x:Name="SwitchTrack" Width="88">
    <Grid x:Name="SwitchBottom" Background="{TemplateBinding SwitchForeground}" Height="32">
        <Rectangle
        x:Name="SwitchBackground"
        Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        Width="76"
        Height="20"
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
            <TranslateTransform x:Name="BackgroundTranslation"/>
        </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
        </Rectangle>
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" BorderThickness="2">
        <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" BorderThickness="4"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <Border
        x:Name="SwitchThumb"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}"
        BorderThickness="4,0"
        Margin="-4,0"
        Width="28"
        Height="36"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
        <Border.RenderTransform>
        <TranslateTransform x:Name="ThumbTranslation"/>
        </Border.RenderTransform>
        <Border
        x:Name="ThumbCenter"
        BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
        BorderThickness="2"
        Background="White"/>
    </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I would suggest using a different colour where the resource `PhoneForegroundBrush` is used.

Comment: I cannot see the label/switch description anywhere above..?

Comment: You said you want to change the foreground color of the switch, then you will need to alter the BorderBrush="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}" part of the template

Answer (score 1):

I think you will need to define a new **Template** for the control and then change your style as you see fit.

You can do this by right clicking on your control and select Edit Template and then create your **Edit a Copy**. This will create a new Style for you that you can change.

Comment: The problem is that the control doesn't have a toggle description text element in its style so there appears to be no way to style it by creating a new template....?